# Error: La variable no está definida

Tags: javascript

Esta variable `subCategoria.name` que intento pasar como parámetro de `categorias` me da un error diciendo que no está definida, en el error puedo ver el contenido de la variable y es correcto, las otras dos variables de tipo numérico no me dan problemas.

No sé a qué se puede deber, creo que debe de ser algo relacionado con las comillas.

El lenguaje que estoy usando es JavaScript, como se ve, asigno en una variable una cadena en la que llamo a la función `categorias` con sus respectivos parámetros. De esas tres variables, solo `subCategoria.name` es de tipo texto.

El error exacto dice:

> La variable "hogar" no esta definida.

(Hogar es el contenido de la variable `subCategoria.name`). El error lo da justo al llamar a la función categorias:

```
menuCate+= '<li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in" onClick="categorias('+subCategoria.id+','+subCategoria.name+','+indice+'); " ><b>'+subCategoria.name+'</b></a></li>' + //Pinto la subCategoria
```

Aquí dejo una demo para que se vea el problema (pulsa en "hogar" para ver el error):

```js
var menuCate = "";
var subCategoria = {
  id: 1,
  name: "hogar"
}
var indice = 2;

menuCate+= '<li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in" onClick="categorias('+subCategoria.id+','+subCategoria.name+','+indice+'); " ><b>'+subCategoria.name+'</b></a></li>'; //Pinto la subCategoria

document.getElementById("categorias").innerHTML = menuCate;
```

```html
<ul id="categorias">
</ul>
```

Comment: Lorenzo, ¿cómo podremos saber el problema si ni siquiera indicas el lenguaje o plataforma con el que estás trabajando, ni el contexto de donde viene la ¿variable o elemento u objeto? `subCategoria` ... Es preciso que mejores tu pregunta, explicando con mayor claridad la situación. Gracias.

Comment: Deberías copiar el error exacto y cuándo te da. Viendo tu código, el error te diría que es que subCategoria.name es una cadena y no la estás poniendo entre comillas, entonces el valor que tenga JavaScript lo va a intentar interpretar como una variable cuando pulses en el enlace.

Comment: Sinceramente.. aquí parece que estamos para corregir faltas de ortografía y  poco mas.. Tan mal está planteada la pregunta... La cuestión es.... por que falla la variable texto en esa cadena.... si os pongo las 4 funciones que tiene que ver con esta, son mas de 600 lineas de código que sinceramente no vienen al caso.

Comment: @LorenzoMartín después de ver tu edición, mi comentario es la solución a tu problema, pero con la información contenida en la pregunta entonces era casi imposible verificarlo, y por eso te pedía más datos. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve], y ten en cuenta que la gente que te dejó comentarios lo hizo con buena intención y para poder ayudarte.

Comment: te falta poner **;** despues de la llave *}*

Comment: @ReneLimon eso es un ejemplo que puse yo para ilustrar el problema.

Comment: Aparte, el `;` no es obligatorio en JavaScript (aunque no está de más tenerlo). Eso no va a afectar a cómo falla `subCategoria.name` (como puede verse en la demo de arriba).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que la variable subcategoria.name es de tipo cadena y por lo tanto debe ir entrecomillada. De lo contrario, cuando se pulse en el enlace el navegador va a interpretar "hogar" como la variable `hogar` (no definida) y te mostrará el mensaje que ves.

La solución es sencilla: pon unas comillas (escapadas por estar dentro de una cadena) para evitar el problema. Algo como esto:

```
menuCate+= '<li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in" onClick="categorias('+subCategoria.id+',\''+subCategoria.name+'\','+indice+'); " ><b>'+subCategoria.name+'</b></a></li>' + //Pinto la subCategoria
```

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
var menuCate = "";
var subCategoria = {
  id: 1,
  name: "hogar"
}
var indice = 2;

menuCate+= '<li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in" onClick="categorias('+subCategoria.id+',\''+subCategoria.name+'\','+indice+'); " ><b>'+subCategoria.name+'</b></a></li>'; //Pinto la subCategoria

document.getElementById("categorias").innerHTML = menuCate;

function categorias(a, b, c) { 
  console.log("Llamaste a categorias sin problema!"); 
}
```

```html
<ul id="categorias">
</ul>
```